# SI Unit Volt Ampere (VA) printed wrongly with space

Tags: siunitx

The symbol Voltampere VA should be printed without space between V and A, is there a way to correct that with siunitx?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
    \begin{document}
    \SI{10}{\volt\ampere}

    10 VA
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no difference between the multiplication here and in other cases (e.g. `\volt\metre` or `\kilogram\ampere`). Dealing with the kerning is a bit of a problem, but there certainly should be a space if you use one in other cases.

Comment: @JosephWright: Voltampere is a special unit for apparent power and so there shouldn't be a space. A normal engineer only writes `\watt` :-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Perhaps 'in use', but from a unit-analysis POV it's two units (one base, one named). As you indicate in your answer, the way to deal with these 'special cases' is to define a custom unit (see `\kWh` for example).

Comment: There's no symbol "voltampere" in the SI.

Comment: I (and ISO 80000-6 sec.6-57a) agree with @JosephWright: it's correct to write `\volt\ampere`

Comment: @Luigi: Please be aware. In Germany we have DIN1301 which specifies your ISO. However `\volt\ampere` indicates two units whereby Volt-ampere is only one unit. (This is my understanding)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define your own units by `\DeclareSIUnit`. In your case I suggest:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit \voltampere { VA } %apparent power 
\DeclareSIUnit \var { var } %volt-ampere reactive - idle power 
\begin{document}
    \SI{10}{\voltampere}
\end{document}
```

I changed the document class from `minimal` to `article`. The drawbacks of the document class are described here: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: @doncherry: Changed.

Comment: At least in my case, Debian with texlive & texlive-science, I get to large of a space with this definition. It should be `\DeclareSIUnit \voltampere {VA} %apparent power`. Single spaces does matter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with TWh having a space between TW and h. To solve this I add an additional curly bracket at `\tera\watt\hour`:

```
\newcommand{\TWh}[1]{\SI{#1}{{\tera\watt\hour}}}
```

instead of

```
\newcommand{\TWh}[1]{\SI{#1}{\tera\watt\hour}}
```